# Multiple Duplicated Queries - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm first showing the code written in my controller:

```
public function __construct(Utility $utility)
{
 $league = $utility->checkDomainController();
 view()->share('league', $league);
 $this->league = $league;
}

public function getDashboard()
{
 return view('dashboard.dashboard', compact('activities'));
}
```

Now I want to share **$league** in all the views in the methods present there in the controller. ( $league consists of one query only ).

But now what problem I'm facing is, query gets duplicated with the number **Included Views** with the **Main View**. Here dashboard is the main view. So now if 7 views are included in Main View then query on **$league** gets executed 7 times. Below are the pictures:

Picture of views included in dashboard.blade.php
[image: Picture of views included in dashboard.blade.php]

Picture of Queries getting duplicated
[image: Picture of Queries getting duplicated]

Any solution to this? Any better way to handle this?

Comment: Can you show your view code where you call this `$league` variable?

Comment: I'm using that variable at many places on my view, but problem is with the views and partials which are included with the main view. If I return a plain view then query is just executed once.

Comment: Are you sending the variable to the partials?

Comment: @Jerodev Yes, this view()->share('league', $league); thing will share variable with all partials that is the problem, so the more the number of partials the more times the query will be duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

A few solutions open to you.

One solution would be to cache the query. Only efficient if your `$league` data does not frequently change.

```
$league = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function () {
    return $utility->checkDomainController();
});
```

Another solution would be to use View Composer. It will be called only when that specific view is rendered. So if you include it once, it renders once.

```
View::composer('leagues', function ($view) {
    //
});
```

Read more about view composers here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers

Comment: I will be trying this and will let you. I highly appreciate your help for this

Comment: but what if I don't want to share leagues with some of the views. Can I do something with middleware?

Comment: THis will be linked to that specific view. Not to all views.

Comment: okay right, but now the problem is there are lots of views, so should I mention all those views here?

Comment: On the above example you mentioned View::composer('leagues', function ($view) {
    //
});, is "leagues" view?

Comment: I got how to use View Composer, but is there any way if I don't want to share that variable for some of the views. Is there any method to exclude those views?

Comment: If got how to use view composer then you should no view is sharing it until you manually bind it to that view. You have to manually call it in a view for it to share it.

Comment: Right, got it, So I need to bind all the views in which I need that :). Thank you for the help. It will really help me.